# Radio Buttons in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm bit new to .NET.
I am using Radio buttons inside a panel in a web page. (Since group boxes are not there).
But when I click on each radio button they all are checked. They are not acting as a group but single units.

Do I need to remove the panel here? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Radiobuttonlist** in ASP.NET toolbar.

And in the SelectedIndexChanged event of the **radiobuttonlist** you can do what ever you want as you wish. (rblist is the **radiobuttonlist**)

```
protected void rbList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbList.Items[0].Selected)
    {
        lblHeader.Text = "You selected first option";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JCTLK... This was useful.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably missing GroupName

```
<asp:RadioButton id="button1" runat="server" GroupName="MyGroup" Text="Button 1" />
<asp:RadioButton id="button2" runat="server" GroupName="MyGroup" Text="Button 2" />
<asp:RadioButton id="button3" runat="server" GroupName="MyGroup" Text="Button 3" />
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `<asp:RadioButtonList>`.